# Haskell Applicative idiom?

Tags: haskell, idioms

I'm new to Haskell and am puzzling over how to best express some operations in the most idiomatic and clear way. Currently (there will be more to come) I'm puzzling over [`<*>`](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) (I'm not even sure what to call that).

For example, if I have, say

```
f = (^2)
g = (+10)
```

as representative functions (in practice they are more complex, but the key thing here is that they are different and distinct), then

```
concatMap ($ [1,2,3,4,10]) [(f <$>), (g <$>) . tail . reverse]
```

and

```
concat $ [(f <$>), (g <$>) . tail . reverse] <*> [[1,2,3,4,10]]
```

accomplish the same thing.

Is one of these more idiomatic Haskell, does one imply something an experienced reader of Haskell that the other does not. Perhaps there are additional (better) ways to express exactly the same thing. Are there conceptual differences between the two approaches that a novice Haskeller like myself may be missing?

Comment: Is your input only ever going to be one list?  If so, the former is clearly better.  By input I mean the list of numbers.

Comment: @itsbruce: Good point. Yes, only ever a single list.

Comment: Combining the `Applicative` or `Functor` instance for lists with `concat` feels very suspicious. `Functor+return+join=Monad`, and for lists, `concat=join`. So if you're mapping and then concatenating, `concatMap` or `=<<` may be more concise.

Comment: @dfeuer: That sounds like it could be very enlightening (if I understood it; remember: beginner). Can you elaborate.

Comment: `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`. Can you implement that using `=<<`? Can you implement `=<<` using `fmap` and `join`? GHC's typed holes may help.

Comment: @dfeuer: Now I'm even more intrigued (but no more enlightened; remember: beginner!)

Comment: I suggested some things in chat.

Comment: @itsbruce: Since it is only ever a single list, how about `mconcat` as suggested in @Lee's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32483045/656912)?

Comment: His is the best answer yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both your functions `(f <$>)` and `(g <$>).tail.reverse` return a monoid type (list in this case) so you can use `mconcat` to convert them into a single function. Then you can apply this function directly to the input list instead of wrapping it in another list and using `concatMap`:

```
mconcat [(f <$>), (g <$>).tail.reverse] $ [1,2,3,4,10]
```

To expand on this, a function `a -> b` is an instance of `Monoid` if `b` is a monoid. The [implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-255) of `mappend` for such functions is:

```
mappend f g x = f x `mappend` g x
```

or equivalently

```
mappend f g = \x -> (f x) `mappend` (g x)
```

so given two functions `f` and `g` which return a monoid type `b`, `f`mappend`g` returns a function which applies its argument to `f` and `g` and combines the results using the `Monoid` instance of `b`.

`mconcat` has type `Monoid a => [a] -> a` and combines all the elements of the input list using `mappend`.

Lists are monoids where `mappend` == `(++)` so

```
mconcat [(f <$>), (g <$>).tail.reverse]
```

returns a function like

```
\x -> (fmap f x) ++ (((fmap g) . tail . reverse) x)
```

Comment: This is quite interesting. It did take me some time to understand, but [the source for the function instance of `Monoid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-255) clears things up.  `(f <$>)` evaluates to `([f] <*>)` which has type `[a] -> [a]`, its return type `[a]` is an instance of `Monoid`, making the function an instance of `Monoid` itself.

Comment: @SamvanHerwaarden: I see that `(f <$>) :: [a] -> [a]` but am having trouble visualizing what kind of a function `mconcat [(f <$>), (g <$>).tail.reverse]` is. I see that it must be `(Num b) => [b] -> [b]`, but can't quite visualize what it "looks" like.

Comment: I said `[a] -> [a]` but you're right about the `Num` constraint, that holds here as well (I was sloppy and omitted it). `mconcat` intersperses a list with `mappend` so we get `mconcat [(f <$>), (g <$>) . tail . reverse] = \x -> (([f] <$>) x) \`mappend\` (((g <$>) . tail . reverse) x)` so all functions in the list are supplied with the argument supplied to `mconcat func`, the outputs of these functions are then concatenated with `mappend`. In our case the functions output lists so `mappend = (++)`, for other monoids the corresponding `mappend` would be used.

Comment: @SamvanHerwaarden: Yeah, I guess what feels weird (and also cool and powerful) is that `mappend` not only "concatenates" functions, but also the outputs of the functions. It's also a bit weird that application of "concatenated" functions even works (because I think of it naively as still being a list of functions rather than one). Should those aspects be obvious, or are they merely a consequence of how `mappend` is implanted for functions?

Comment: It was not obvious to me, I only got it after checking the `Monoid` instance for functions. Still, I think there are not many other ways to implement the instance meaningfully, so in that sense I would say it is the 'obvious' implementation. I agree that it seems weird, cool and powerful, personally I wouldn't quickly use it in code I expect other people to read later on.

Comment: I was too fast saying I wouldn't use it in code I expect people to read. I will probably run into situations where this pattern expresses exactly what I intend to do. (Maybe I would add a comment to clarify what's going on though ;) )

Comment: @SamvanHerwaarden: Exactly. It's not that obvious to me either, except in the sense that there really aren't that many other rational ways to implement it (given the required signature). Also, I agree about use, and here I think it's perfect.

Comment: @SamvanHerwaarden: One clarification, now that I ponder this: you say that the outputs of the `mappend`ed functions are themselves `mappend`ed. Does that mean that for `(f <> g) x` to work, not only must `f` and `g` be Monoids (which functions are); but also that `f x` and `f g` must be Monoids also (which they are here, since `[]` is a Monoid)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius - Functions are only monoids if the return type `b` is a monoid, see update.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! So `((+1) <> (^2)) 5` won't work because nether `+` nor `^` return Monoids (`Int` is not a Monoid?; I thought it was)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius - Plain `Int`s are not monoids, you need to wrap them in `Sum` or `Product` to select the monoid instance you want e.g. `getSum $ Sum . (+1) <> Sum . (^2) $ 4`

Comment: Ah good, so it makes sense at least: a plain `Int` *isn't* a Monoid (though lots of sites say — somewhat imprecisely I gather — that they are).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius - Monoids comprise of a set, an associative binary operation and an identity element for the operation so it is imprecise to state that some type is a monoid without also specifying the operation as well. `Int`s form monoids in a few ways e.g `+` and `*`, and Haskell uses `newtype` wrappers to let you choose the instance you want. There are similar wrappers for `Bool` and `Maybe a` defined in `Data.Monoid`.

Comment: That makes sense. So when people say "`Int` forms a Monoid", they don't mean it *is a* Monoid, but that it *can be*, suitably wrapped and packaged with a suitable operation.

Answer (score 9):

Personally for your example I would write

```
f = (^2)
g = (+10)

let xs = [1,2,3,4,10]
in (map f xs) ++ (map g . tail $ reverse xs)
```

In a very Applicative "mood", I would replace the part after `in` by

```
((++) <$> map f <*> map g . tail . reverse) xs
```

which I actually don't think is more readable in this case. If you don't directly understand what it means, spend some time on understanding the `Applicative` instance of `((->) a)` (`Reader`).

I think the choice really depends on what you're trying to do, i.e. what your output is supposed to mean. In your example the task is very abstract (basically just showcasing what `Applicative` can do), so it's not directly obvious which version to use.

The `Applicative` instance of `[]` intuitively relates to combinations, so I would use it in a situation like this:

```
-- I want all pair combinations of 1 to 5
(,) <$> [1..5] <*> [1..5]
```

If you would have many functions, and you would want to try all combinations of these functions with a number of arguments, I would indeed use the `[]` instance of `Applicative`. But if what you're after is a concatenation of different transformations I would write it as such (which I did, above).

Just my 2 cents as a medium-experience Haskeller.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes struggle with the similar problem. You have single element but multiple functions.

Usually we have multiple elements, and single function: so we do:

```
map f xs
```

But it's not the problem in Haskell. The dual is as easy:

```
map ($ x) fs
```

The fact, that your `x` is actually a list, and you want to `concat` after the `map`, so you do

```
concatMap ($ xs) fs
```

---

I cannot really understand what happens in the second equation directly, even I can reason it does the same as first one using applicative laws.